# Outlook Fields and Equivalent Properties

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have a macro to get in excel all the emails from a shared mailbox
In my shared inbox I have created 2 new fields where we enter some information related to the emails received. I have named them Client and Oper.

Can you help me please with a suggestion? How can I see the field property in order to get it in VBA?

The macro looks like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub getDataFromOutlook()
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
Dim i As Integer
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objOwner = OutlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("Sharedmailbox@companyname.com")
objOwner.Resolve
If objOwner.Resolved Then
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)
End If
i = 1
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("email_receipt_date").Value Then
Range("email_sender").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("email_sender").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
        Range("email_sender").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        Range("email_subject").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("email_subject").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
        Range("email_subject").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
      'Range("email_client").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Client
      'Range("email_client").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
        'Range("email_client").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        'Range("email_oper").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Oper
        'Range("email_oper").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
        'Range("email_oper").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        Range("email_date").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("email_date").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
        Range("email_date").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        Range("email_categories").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Categories
        Range("email_categories").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
        Range("email_categories").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        Range("email_flag_status").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.FlagStatus
        Range("email_flag_status").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
        Range("email_flag_status").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
 i = i + 1
    End If
Next OutlookMail
Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps OutlookMail.UserProperties("FieldName") .Value?  There are a couple diff ways to implement new fields. Some are calcuated view columns and some are in forms. Where are these new fields?

Comment: The columns were added in the shared mailbox by creating them following the menu: view tab->view settings - >columns->new column. The type of columns is text

Comment: Then yes, what I posted will work. Further research indicates issues when the field is not populated, so its suggested to use the Find method to ensure the value is populated before attempting to copy it otherwise it will throw an error.  See this answer for more details.  I can mock up an example if you need more help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551655/how-to-read-custom-field-value-of-outlook

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `UserProperties` of the MailItem.

For example `OutlookMail.UserProperties("Oper").Value` will return the value of that property field you created.

Note that it WILL cause an error it that field is not populated so it is suggested to use `Find` beforehand with an IF check to ensure you don't throw an exception.

```
If Not(OutlookMail.UserProperties.Find("Oper", True) Is Nothing) Then
    'Do stuff with OutlookMail.UserProperties("Oper").Value
End If
```