# Import Outlook User-Defined Field to Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, import, outlook

I would like to import mail data from Outlook.

I have no problem to import classic fields such as: From, Subject ... etc. I cannot find how to import my "User-defined field".

The User-defined field is named "DemandQTY" and contains only numbers.

I get my data from a shared mailbox.

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutNS As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
Dim FileName As String
Dim MI As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Item As Object
Dim Atmt As Attachment

Set OutNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
Set objOwner = OutNS.CreateRecipient("emailadress")
objOwner.Resolve

If objOwner.Resolved Then
    Set Folder = OutNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)

    i=2
    For Each OutMail In Folder.Items
        Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) = OutMail.EntryID
        ' (etc....)
        Sheets(2).Cells(i, 32) = OutMail.ReminderTime    
        i = i + 1
    Next OutMail
    MsgBox "Importation Terminée"
    Sheets(2).Select
    Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Select
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set OutNS = Nothing
    Set Folder = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

I tried different methods found on internet, but nothing worked.

Comment: See answer detailing UDF properties here. 
 Replace the "Oper" with your "DemandQTY". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58168779/outlook-fields-and-equivalent-properties?noredirect=1#comment102726812_58168779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by first testing if the property exists.  If it doesn't and you try to work with it, it will throw an error. Afterwards we can access the value if the property is found.

```
For Each OutMail In Folder.Items

        Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) = OutMail.EntryID
       (etc....)
        Sheets(2).Cells(i, 32) = OutMail.ReminderTime

        If Not(OutMail.UserProperties.Find("DemandQTY", True) Is Nothing) Then    
            Sheets(2).Cells(i, 33) = OutMail.UserProperties("DemandQTY").Value
        End If

        i = i + 1
Next OutMail
```

Comment: Hey Mike. Thank you for your response : it works ! I am certain I tried Sheets(2).Cells(i, 33) = OutMail.UserProperties("DemandQTY").Value this morning but it did not work for some reasons. I knew it was simple but I was so frustrated. Anyway, thanks again.